# Save grid plots drawn within a loop automatically in R

Tags: r, gridview, plot, time-series

I have time-series data of 6 months and I want to plot it in grid manner like this
[image]

As a reproducible example, let us the following code:

```
library(xts)
seq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-03-01"),as.POSIXct("2015-03-30"), by = "60 mins")
timeseries_ob <- xts(data.frame(rnorm(length(seq),30,2)),seq)
looplength <- length(unique(.indexmday(timeseries_ob)))
par(mfrow=c(4,3))
pdf("temp.pdf")
for(i in 1:looplength){
  daydata <- timeseries_ob[.indexmday(timeseries_ob)%in%i,]
  plot(daydata,type="l",main="")
}
dev.off()
```

With this code, plots get automatically saved, but they are not in the grid manner. Each plot gets saved in different page of pdf. Is there any other way to save above plots in a grid manner automatically.

Note: I don't want to use `facet_grid`, because these plots are generated within a loop and I believe with `ggplot` it might become complex to draw.

Comment: ever used `par(mfrow = c(4,3))` between `pdf(..)` and `dev.off()`?

Comment: Really, a serious blunder. Spent about one hour on this issue. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `par(mfrow = c(4,3))` command between `pdf(...)` and `dev.off()`.
This will lead to your desired result!